# Accessing a variable inside a timeout function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout

In the following code segment I want timeDiff to be available to be set on waitingTime. But I understand that timeDiff inside the inner function would get value only when it's getting executed. How to use element's TIMEDIFF to set timeout for the give function?

```
  var timeDiff;
  for (var i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
      (function() {

          timeouts.push($timeout(function() {
              var element = q.shift(); // q is a queue
              timeDiff = element.TIMEDIFF;
              console.log(element.TIMEDIFF); //3000 
              broadcastData(element);
          }, waitingTime));

          // console.log(timeDiff + " timeiff");

          waitingTime = waitingTime + timeDiff; // 1000 + 3000
      })();
  }
```

In simple terms waitingTime should depend on element.TIMEDIFF. How to achieve that?

Comment: Is the goal that each function in `timeouts`  will set waitingTime for the next function?

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this? I've made it a bit generic, but it should do what you're hoping to achieve. [Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/dFBPk2mfxDTTvIwopAs0) here. The time for the next function and is completely configurable from within the currently executing function.

```
  var waitingTime = 100;
  var q = {length: 100};
  var i = 0;
  var timeouts = [$timeout(getTimeDiff, waitingTime).then(callback)];

  function callback(newTime) {
    while(i < q.length) {
      i++;
      var promise = $timeout(getTimeDiff, newTime).then(callback);
      timeouts.push(promise);
      return promise;
    }
  }

  function getTimeDiff() {
      //here is where you would access the q and get the timediff
      waitingTime += Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
      console.log(waitingTime + " until next tick");
      return waitingTime;
  }
```

Comment: did you test it? I don't think this will work. Will try it though. When timeout functions are set waitingtime should be available afaik.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. I think a structure like this will work, taking advantage of the fact that $timeout is a promise.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed a little bit, I hope that works for you.

```
var timeDiff;
for (var i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
    var element = q[i];
    timeDiff = element.TIMEDIFF;

    timeouts.push(setTimeout(function(data) {
        broadcastData(data.e);
    }, waitingTime, {e:element}));

    waitingTime = waitingTime + timeDiff;
}
```

Comment: If we use q.shift() out of the timeout then while loop will empty the queue at the end of the iteration which is not the intended behavior.

Comment: what if we don't use q.shift() then? getting the elements by their keys.. is that work?